# Optimize Julia code to improve on quadratic complexity

Tags: performance, julia

I'm currently working on a simulation that unfortunately has a time complexity of O(n²).
The simulator and code base is all in Python, however the heavy weight calculations I tried to offload to Julia to save some time. Since each iteration of my simulation compares 100 instances with each other we end up with 4900 comparisons each round. Doing this in Python took about 63sec, and I managed to get it down to 30 by using Julia.

I'm quite sure my code is far from optimal since this is my first program I wrote in Julia. How can I improve it?

`calculate_novelty` is called by the Python script and `histograms` is a vector of size 100 containing 20x20 matrices

```
using Shuffle

function apply_noise_mask(hist, INT_CASTER::UInt)
    diff::UInt = INT_CASTER - sum(hist)

    mask = zeros(UInt, size(hist))
    mask = shuffle(replace(mask, 0=>1, count=diff))
    return hist + mask
end

function move_supply(supply, fcoord::CartesianIndex , capacity, tcoord::CartesianIndex, INT_CASTER::UInt)
    if supply[fcoord] <= capacity[tcoord]
        flow = supply[fcoord]
        capacity[tcoord] -= flow
        supply[fcoord]= 0
    else
        flow = capacity[tcoord]
        supply[fcoord] -= flow
        capacity[tcoord] = 0
    end
    distance = sqrt(abs(fcoord[1]-tcoord[1])^2 + abs(fcoord[2]-tcoord[2])^2)
    score = flow/INT_CASTER*distance
    return score, supply, capacity
end

function wasserstein_distance(hist0, hist1, INT_CASTER::UInt)::Float16
    supply, capacity = trunc.(UInt, hist0.*INT_CASTER), trunc.(UInt, hist1.*INT_CASTER)
    supply, capacity = apply_noise_mask(supply, INT_CASTER), apply_noise_mask(capacity, INT_CASTER)

    score::Float16 = 0
    while true
        from_idx, to_idx = findfirst(supply .> 0), findfirst(capacity .> 0)

        if (from_idx == nothing) || (to_idx == nothing)
            return score
        end
        work, supply, capacity = move_supply(supply, from_idx, capacity, to_idx, INT_CASTER)
        score += work
    end
end

function calculate_novelty(histograms)
    @time begin

        INT_CASTER::UInt = 10000
        amt_instances::UInt = length(histograms) # population = 100 -> int8 goes until 127

        novelty_scores = zeros(Float16, amt_instances)
        for i = 1:amt_instances-1
            for j = 1+i:amt_instances
                score = wasserstein_distance(histograms[i], histograms[j], INT_CASTER)
                novelty_scores[i] += score
                novelty_scores[j] += score
            end
        end
    end
    return novelty_scores
end
```

Timing it gives values like this:

```
15.760257 seconds (20.87 M allocations: 28.901 GiB, 11.97% gc time)
15.592724 seconds (20.72 M allocations: 28.697 GiB, 11.95% gc time)
```

Julia version: 1.8

**EDIT:** one major improvement was to switch out `findfirst` with a custom function:

```
function find_first_candidate(arr)
    for elem in CartesianIndices(arr)
       if arr[elem] > 0
          return elem
        end
    end
    return nothing
end
```

This is an average run now:

```
1.095999 seconds (99.02 k allocations: 314.210 MiB, 1.74% gc time)
```

Using in-place functions as DNF suggested made the average run:

```
1.090733 seconds (59.41 k allocations: 188.528 MiB, 1.70% gc time)
```

Comment: Why are you using `Float16`? That could be slow. Also, use in-place functions `shuffle!(replace!(mask, 0=>1, count=diff))` and `mask .+= hist` to save allocations.

Comment: I would expect `mask[1:count] = 1` to be faster than `replace!`

Comment: Thanks for all the comment! As i said this is my first time with Julia so every tip is appreciated!

Comment: If you want further speedups, you need to share how your code is called, by providing some example histograms.

Comment: im not sure how to show them properly since they are quite big. but essentially the histograms variable is passed from a python ndarray. the elements of which are 20x20 matrices that contain floats ranging from 0 to 1, those matrices are very sparse in nature.
Should i try to add one in the question?

Also I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Can you just create random values for the histograms? You don't need to paste the actual values in, just show how to generate them with random values.

Comment: those histograms are generated in python, but you could do this in julia: rand(20,20).
Its not exactly the same since all elements of the matrix have to add up to 1, but for testing purposes the rand(20,20) should be almost the same

Comment: But what's the histogram part of this? A matrix isn't a histogram, or what's going on?

Comment: ok sorry for not clarifying. The matrix is the representation of a 2d histogram. Does this make it clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [ProfileView.jl](https://github.com/timholy/ProfileView.jl) I can see that the slowest part is there:

```
from_idx, to_idx = findfirst(supply .> 0), findfirst(capacity .> 0)
```

`supply .> 0` `capacity .> 0` materialize two arrays at each loop and `findfirst` is quite slow (or called a lot of times).

I'm not sure if the translation is easy but you should try the wasserstein distance from
[OptimalTransport.jl](https://juliaoptimaltransport.github.io/OptimalTransport.jl/stable/#ExactOptimalTransport.wasserstein)

Comment: wow. i made my own function instead of findfirst and now its running in 1.7 sec instead of 30. Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: try using the predicate form of `findfirst` like this: `from_idx, to_idx = findfirst(>(0), supply), findfirst(>(0), capacity)`